# E/unknown:ReactNative: Unable to launch dev options menu because react activity isn't available

Tags: react-native

I'm currently working on a hybrid React Native / Android app and I'm having issues getting the React Native debug menu to appear.

I've placed:

```
<activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
```

in the debug manifest, and a relevant onKeyUp handler in the RN activity to trigger the menu, but when trying to access this menu the console logs the following:

E/unknown:ReactNative: Unable to launch dev options menu because react activity isn't available

I'm on version 0.54, and the menu works as expected with the standard scaffolded RN app. Fast running out of ideas. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As is bloody typical I solve it as soon as I log it (joy of open source).

In the activity's ReactInstanceManager.builder() method, chain in

```
setCurrentActivity(this)
```

And you're sorted.